# Is projection $P(g) = \arg\min\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}}||g-f||_{2,\mu}^2$ a linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am thinking about the function projection question.

Is projection $$P(g) = \arg\min_{f \in \mathcal{F}}||g-f||_{2,\mu}^2 = \int \left(f(x)-g(x)\right)^2 \mu(dx)$$ a linear operator, i.e., $P(g)-P(f) = P(g-f)$?

$\mathcal{F}$ is a function space.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\|\cdot \|_{2,\mu}$?

Comment: If $\mathcal F$ is a closed subspace of $L^{2}(\mu)$ then It is a bounded linear operator satisfying the following properties: $\|P\|=1$ (assuming  $\mathcal F\neq \{0\}$), $P^{2}=P$ and $P^{*}=P$.

Comment: I add the definition of $||\cdot||_{\mu,2}$ now.

Comment: Thank you Kavi. Could you please provides me with any references?